# how to automatically select the best frame in a video using python?

Tags: python, image-processing

We are doing a project on license plate recognition using python(2.7.12). We have divided the video into frames using the following code:

```
import cv2               #importing opencv library
import numpy             #importing numpy
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Python27/project/license.avi')  #read the video
success,image = cap.read()      #divide into frames
count = 0
success = True
while (cap.isOpened()): 
    success,image = cap.read()  
    print 'Read a new frame: ', success  #when frame has been read successfully
    if (type(image) == type(None)):  #check for invalid frame
            break
    else:
      gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert frame into grey
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, gray_image)     # save frame as JPEG file
    count += 1         #repeat for all the frames
cap.release()
```

We are trying to get the best frame(with high quality).Is it possible to automatically select a frame that has the complete license plate?
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: it depends on how you define **high quality**? According to me perform FFT on the frames and use the frame having minimum blur

Comment: Yeah but we also need to see to it that the particular frame which has been selected using FFT should also contain the whole license plate and not just a part of it(when the video is divided into frames,not all the frames will have the compete plate,some might only have a part of it).How should I implement this?